# Could not acquire change log lock. Currently locked by 'UserName'(IpAddress) since datetime

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am using MSSQL server and inserting change log data while installation using liquibase. while executing liquibase change log file , i am getting below error.

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by 'UserName'(IpAddress) since 4/2/19 12:36 PM

Answer (score 9):

this error occured due to your changelog table's lock is aquire by other user and this entry is added in 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK' table.

solution: remove given entry from 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK' table.

delete FROM [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK] where ID=123

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above solution. All I would added to please run select first to find ID.
step 1:
select * from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
step 2:
delete from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK where ID =?;